# Consuming an asynchronous Geoprocessing service in ESRI's Flex API

Tags: arcgis-server, geoprocessing, arcgis-9.3, flex, arcgis-flex-api

I have been trying to consuming my own asyncronous Geoprocessing service using ESRI's FLEX api, but i am either doing something dumb, or there is some trick involved in getting the results out.

Since it's an asyncronous service, I am using the submitJob()method. The jobComplete event is firing, but the GeoprocessorEvent that i am getting here has a null executeResult.

And if I check using FireBug, I can see that the result is definitely being sent to my browser.

Is there any sample which shows how to get the results  from an asyncronous service?

P.S. I am using ArcGIS server 9.3.1 & Flex API 2.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you check out this sample from ESRI http://resources.esri.com/arcgisserver/apis/flex/index.cfm?fa=codeGalleryDetails&scriptID=15956

Comment: I was searching for exactly something like this. I'll look into this sample & get back to you.

Comment: Thanks Bob, This was exactly what I needed to get my App Working.

Comment: This link appears to be down...Any idea how to find it now?

Comment: I have the same qestion. The Url (http://resources.esri.com/arcgisserver/apis/flex/index.cfm?fa=codeGalleryDetails&scriptID=15956) does not work. do you jave a new one?
Thanks
Tarek

Comment: @Terek, the ArcGIS API for Flex sample mentioned above is now available at http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/flex-api/samples/index.html#/Asynchronous_geoprocessing_Clip_and_ship/01nq0000006t000000/